# How can I check if there is only value changed in a (bitwise?) value?

Tags: bit

How can I check if there is only 1 bit change between a value and another (next) value?

the output is for example

001

101

110

in the second output there is a 0 changed into a 1

in the third output there is a 0 changed into a 1 AND also the last 1 changed into a 0

the program may only continue if there is only 1 change.

Comment: use AND operator, if(operand1 & operand2 == 1) there is only one bit change.

Comment: My guess is that you would have to loop through the previous `String` with the current one and compare each character with each other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Answer (score 3):

First, XOR the two numbers. XOR will return a 1 for every bit that changed.

Example:

0101110110100100

XOR

0100110110100100

would give you

0001000000000000

Now what you need is a quick way to check if there is only a single bit in your resulting number, or in other words, if the resulting number is a power of two.

A quick test for that is: `(x & (x - 1)) == 0`.

No for loops needed.

Comment: thanks, I made this sofar: but your code is way better                                                                 <?php

 

    function _xor($text,$key){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){
        $text[$i] = intval($text[$i])^intval($key[$i]);
    }
    return $text;
    }

    echo  _xor('01100001','01100010');
    $new = _xor('01100001','01100010');

    if ($new > 1) {
    echo " a is bigger than 1 b, begin opnieuw";
    } elseif ($new == $new) {
    echo "a is equal to b ";
    } else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the bitwise XOR and then just count the bits that are 1's. This is known as the Hamming distance. For example:

```
unsigned int a = 0b001;
unsigned int b = 0b100;
unsigned int res;
/* Stores the number of different bits */
unsigned int acc;

res = a ^ b;

/* from https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html */
for (acc = 0; res; res >>= 1)
{
  acc += res & 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`

```
void main(String[] args){
    boolean value = moreThanOneChanged("101", "001");
}

static boolean moreThanOneChanged(String input, String current){

    if(input.length() != current.length()) return false;

    char[] first = input.toCharArray();

    char[] second = current.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        if(first[i] == second[i])
            j++;
        if(j > 1)
            return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it to yourself fairly easily by using an `and` comparison between an `exclusive or` of each value and the `exclusive or minus 1`. It is easier to visualize what takes place by looking at the binary representation of the values and results. Below the function `onebitoff` performs the test. The other functions just provide a way to output the results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>   /* for CHAR_BIT */

#define WDSZ 64

/** returns pointer to binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'.
  *  returns pointer to string contianing binary representation of
  *  unsigned 64-bit (or less ) value zero padded to 'sz' digits.
  */
char *cpbin (unsigned long n, int sz) 
{
    static char s[WDSZ + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + WDSZ;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        p--;
        *p = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';
    }

    return p;
}

/* return true if one-bit bitwise variance */
int onebitoff (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return ((a ^ b) & ((a ^ b) - 1)) ? 0 : 1;
}

/* quick output of binary difference for 2 values */
void showdiff (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    if (onebitoff (a, b))
        printf ( " values %u, %u - vary by one-bit (bitwise)\n\n", a, b);
    else 
        printf ( " values %u, %u - vary by other than one-bit (bitwise)\n\n", a, b);

    printf ("  %3u : %s\n", a, cpbin (a, sizeof (char) * CHAR_BIT));
    printf ("  %3u : %s\n", b, cpbin (b, sizeof (char) * CHAR_BIT));
    printf ("  xor : %s\n\n",  cpbin ((a ^ b), sizeof (char) * CHAR_BIT));
}

int main () {

    printf ("\nTest whether the following numbers vary by a single bit (bitwise)\n\n");

    showdiff (1, 5);
    showdiff (5, 6);
    showdiff (6, 1);
    showdiff (97, 105);  /* just as a further test */

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

$ ./bin/bitsvary

```
Test whether the following numbers vary by a single bit (bitwise)

 values 1, 5 - vary by one-bit (bitwise)

    1 : 00000001
    5 : 00000101
  xor : 00000100

 values 5, 6 - vary by other than one-bit (bitwise)

    5 : 00000101
    6 : 00000110
  xor : 00000011

 values 6, 1 - vary by other than one-bit (bitwise)

    6 : 00000110
    1 : 00000001
  xor : 00000111

 values 97, 105 - vary by one-bit (bitwise)

   97 : 01100001
  105 : 01101001
  xor : 00001000
```

Comment: thanks all!!! really great comments. from everyone! stack overflow rulez, we made our function work perfectly because of all the help.